# Download files from multiple links in google cloud storage

Tags: file, google-cloud-platform, command-line, download

I have 1000 files in google cloud storage but these files in multiple directories so, how can I download them at the same time

I put all the links in excel file and use this command

```
cat C:/Users/tm/files.xlsx | C:/Users/tm/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud_SDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil.cmd -m cp -I C:/Users/tm/Desktop/files
```

then I got this massege
stat: embedded null character in path
CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

```
gsutil -m cp -R gs://your-bucket-name/path/to/directory/ C:/Users/tma/Desktop/files
```

Comment: but the files in different directories

Comment: You should be able to use a wildcard as well in this command.

Comment: should I use google cloud SDK shell? also all the links in the excel file